# Creating an empty profile on devise registration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have used devise for authentication in a rails app and I want a user to be able to sign up and once signed up be able to edit their own profile. I've followed along with other answers on stack but when I try and register using the default devise registration form I'm getting this error.

```
NoMethodError in Devise::RegistrationsController#create

undefined method `create' for nil:NilClass

app/models/user.rb:17:in `create_profile'
```

My User.rb is as follows

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

   has_one :profile

   attr_accessible :login, :username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :profile_attributes

   attr_accessor :login
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile

   validates :username,  :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false }, :presence => true

   after_create :create_profile

   def create_profile
      self.profile.create
   end

   def self.find_first_by_auth_conditions(warden_conditions)
      conditions = warden_conditions.dup
      if login = conditions.delete(:login)
         where(conditions).where(["username = :value OR lower(email) = lower(:value)", { :value => login }]).first
      else
          where(conditions).first
      end
   end
 end
```

Profile.rb is

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :fax, :phone_1, :phone_2, :url

  belongs_to :user
end
```

profiles controller is the norm apart from the edit action

```
def edit
   @profile = current_user.profile
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `self.create_profile` instead of `self.profile.create` for `has_one` association.

Example

```
An Account class declares has_one :beneficiary, which will add:

Account#beneficiary (similar to Beneficiary.where(account_id: id).first)

Account#beneficiary=(beneficiary) (similar to beneficiary.account_id = account.id; beneficiary.save)

Account#build_beneficiary (similar to Beneficiary.new("account_id" => id))

Account#create_beneficiary (similar to b = Beneficiary.new("account_id" => id); b.save; b)

Account#create_beneficiary! (similar to b = Beneficiary.new("account_id" => id); b.save!; b)
```

More docs [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_one)

Comment: That throws another error SystemStackError in Devise::RegistrationsController#create. stack level too deep. It gives no indictaion as to what file the error could be coming from

Comment: There must be circular callbacks being fired back and forth between `User` and `Profile` model. Check it in rails console

Comment: How would I check for it?

Comment: Got it, I changed the name of the create_profile method in user.rb to add_profile. final method looks like def add_profile self.create_profile end